# push Notifications after amount of time are not working on IOS, I can get token but doesn't get notifications, react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

The notifications work at the beginning of installing the application, but after some time they stop working, although I retrieve the token correctly and they also work perfectly on Android, but on the iPhone they do not work after some time, to make it works I should delete the app and install it again.

Here is my code:

```
async function requestUserPermission() {
    const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
    const enabled =
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;

    if (enabled) {
    }

    const knowPermission = await messaging().requestPermission({
      sound: true,
      announcement: true,
    });

    console.log('Permission = ', knowPermission);
  }

  const getToken = async () => {
    try {
      const token = await messaging().getToken();

      console.log('============= messaging token =============');
      console.log({token});
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('======== error post token ==========');
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const notficationListener = async () => {
    messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(res => {
      console.log('res: ', res);
    });

    messaging()
      .getInitialNotification()
      .then(remoteMessage => {
        if (remoteMessage) {
          console.log('Notification DATA', JSON.stringify(remoteMessage, null, 3));
        }
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    requestUserPermission();
    getToken();
    notficationListener();
  }, []);
```

I am using

```
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^11.5.0",
"@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^11.5.0",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^11.5.0",
```

I tried to remove the app and install it again and it works, but after time doesn't work